# How can I save a Finplot plot or multiple plots to a pdf file?

Tags: python, plot, pdf-generation, yfinance

I am using Finplot to plot open high low close chart. It works fine, but I want to save the plots to a pdf file. So my question is how to save the plot(s) to pdf file.

I don't know how to print it to a pdf file. But the basic code that creates the plot is as follows: (Please note that in Spyder the plot does not show up in the Plots tab, but as an separate window.

```
   import finplot as fplt
   import yfinance as yf

   import pandas as pd


   symbol="aapl"
   aapl= yf.Ticker(symbol)
   aapl_historical = aapl.history(start="2023-10-28", end="2023-11-29", interval="1d")
   prices=aapl_historical 

   z3=prices.copy(deep=True)
   z3['Date']=z3.index
   print("there")
   z3['Date1']= pd.to_datetime(z3['Date'])
   z3=z3.reset_index(drop=True)
   fplt.candlestick_ochl(z3[['Date1','Open','Low','High','Close']])
   fplt.show()
```

Comment: if it can write image `.png` or `.jpg` then you can later use external programs to convert to PDF - ie. `imagemagic` can do `convert image.png image.pdf`. Of course `Python` has few modules to generate `PDF` and you may need to learn one of them.

Comment: digging in [source code](https://github.com/highfestiva/finplot/blob/master/finplot/__init__.py#L2000) I found it has `fplt.screenshot('image.png')`